# left vs Right politics and liberal vs conservative

Tags: political-theory, ideology, political-system, conservatism, liberalism

Can we say left means liberal and right means conservative ?
In history we see lot of counterexamples.

Comment: No.  At least not in all parts of the world.  You mention "history" so what counterexamples do you already have and why do the "counterexamples" not already answer your question.  You should also look at the relevant wiki pages on "liberalism" and how the term has developed in meaning in different countries.

Comment: @JamesK Could u define what is left and right after incorporating counterexamples.

Comment: No!! Defining "left" and "right" is pretty much impossible. That's kind of the point.

Comment: @Rusi you mean conservative are not progressive

Comment: @Rusi conservatism also don't oppose economic progress see case of India.

Comment: @Rusi any comment on https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/80805/radical-conservatism-vs-conservative-radicalism

Answer (score 2):

In most brands of democracy, citizens get to vote for candidates affilated with a party, and many systems are designed to limit the number of parties (see [Duverger's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duverger%27s_law) or [electoral threshold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_threshold)).

Humans like to classify things in their environment to make sense of them. So these parties get labels, which are developed/negotiated in each political system. What is called liberal in one nation may not be called liberal in another country.

- *Conservative* comes from the Latin word for *preserve*. Most parties labeled conservatives try to preserve *some* aspect of the existing way of life. When they want to restore rather than preserve, they are [reactionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactionary), but political tradition/inertia might mean that they retain the label conservative.
- *Liberal* has a more complex etymology, what it means is given people freedom of choice. There are different brands of liberalism, aiming at social or economic freedom or both.
- The classification from left to right comes from the human desire to put political parties into an [one-dimensional chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left%E2%80%93right_political_spectrum), because people either cannot be bothered to use a [two-dimensional chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_spectrum#Other_double-axis_models) or agree which one to use.